# Join a point with adjacent point from list of points in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

I am creating a grid made up of linestrings by creating a grid and joining the grid points with adjacent grid point but that process is taking too much time.
I am using the following query to join the grid points:

```sql
select ST_MakeLine(a.point_geometry, b.point_geometry)
from grid_points a, grid_points b where
ST_distance(a.point_geometry, b.point_geometry)= 10
```

The distance between adjacent point is `10m`
point_geometry table just hold `Geometry(Point)` column.
Because of the hash join, the query is taking too much time, is there any easy way to generate the grid lines?

Comment: @Kasper I have index on a.geometry and b.geometry and I also tried ST_distance() it's still the same

Comment: Yes its gist index. 
Number of points is around 50k.

Comment: Do you get a result if you set a small limit to the query ?  Distance might not strictly return 10 does it ?

Comment: yes then I get the result pretty quick

Comment: `ST_Distance` cannot utilize an index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your implicit `CROSS JOIN` resolves in a *cartesian product* of `a` & `b`, meaning that you are effectively issuing the `ST_Distance` computation of **2500000000 pairs of points**, with 2-4 duplicates per point in the result set.

---

**Generally:**

To gain index driven performance for distance searches, use a `JOIN` condition on a suitable function to limit candidates to the desired proximity only; using your query and `ST_DWithin`:

```
SELECT
  ST_MakeLine(a.point_geometry, b.point_geometry) AS geom
FROM
  grid_points a
  JOIN
  grid_points b
    ON ST_DWithin(a.point_geometry, b.point_geometry, 10)
WHERE
  -- adding a small threshold to the distance filter
  ST_Distance(a.point_geometry, b.point_geometry)
    BETWEEN  9.99
        AND 10.01
;
```

---

**However:**

As I mentioned above, without exclusion rules or sequence attributes you will end up with a ton of duplicates. I suggest to investigate possibilities to generate a grid of lines directly (alternatively, [`ST_SquareGrid`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SquareGrid.html) returns *Polygons*) or use the (hopefully available) row and column indices of the point grid to create lines between consecutive points e.g. top-to-bottom & left-to-right.